Conditional logic in shopify
I am outputing a value based on collection title in shopify
{% for collection in product.collections %}
                          {% if collection.title contains "China" %} 

This is china

{% endif %}
                {% endfor %} 
{% for collection in product.collections %}
                          {% if collection.title contains "China,vietnam" %} 

This is china and vietnam

{% endif %}
                {% endfor %} 

But the issue iam facing is, it is outputing both values which is
1)This is china
2)This is This is china and vietnam
can someone help to check, where the issue is
But the issue iam facing is, it is outputing both values which is
1)This is china
2)This is This is china and vietnam

Do you explicilty need the "China" items before/after the "china,vietnam" items? Can you share a sample of the product collections and the result you want to display for it?

I have one product which is in both china and vietnam collection, for this it is outputting both results 1)This is china 2) This is china and vietnam , However it should only output : 2)This is china and vietnam

"China" is a subset of "China,vietnam". The question doesn't specify the output you expect, but it seems like you should only iterate the products collection once and use two conditions:
{% for collection in product.collections %}
{% if collection.title contains "China,vietnam" %} 
This is china and vietnam
{% elsif collection.title contains "China" %}
This is china
{% endif %}


This is outputing "This is china" when both collection names have china and vietnam

@RahulDogra are you sure you copied the elsif properly?

yes i have copied it properly

I think you should try this code.
 {% for collection in product.collections %}
{% if collection.title contains "China" and collection.title contains "vietnam" %} 
        This is china and vietnam
      {% elsif collection.title contains "China" %}
        This is china
        {% else %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %} 

